# Cannot display the value of the key in a hash

Tags: hash, radio-button, key

I am using Rails3 and currently using 'active_shipping' gem. When I iterate through collection of rates using the following lines of code:

```
   <%res.rates.sort_by(&:price).each do |rate|%>
   <%service_name = rate.service_name%>
   <%postage_rate = (@bank.get_rate(res.rate_estimates[0].currency,:USD)
   * (rate.price).to_f/100).round(2)%>
   <%=service_name%>, <%=postage_rate%>
```

I get the following output:

UPS Standard, 40.93
UPS Saver, 73.56
UPS Express, 76.54
UPS Worldwide Express Plus, 129.16

Then when I use hash where service_name is a key and postage_rate is a value.

```
 <%records = {service_name => postage_rate }%>
```

Then I create radio_buttons:

```
<%records.each do |key,value|  %> 
<%=f.radio_button :service_name,key%> <%="#{key}, #{value}" %><br/>
```

[image]

The whole code is as follow:

```
 <%res.rates.sort_by(&:price).each do |rate|%>
 <%service_name = rate.service_name%>
 <%postage_rate = (@bank.get_rate(res.rate_estimates[0].currency,:USD)
 * (rate.price).to_f/100).round(2)%>

 <%records = {service_name => postage_rate }%>

  <%records.each do |key,value|  %> 
  <%=f.radio_button :service_name,key%> <%="#{key}, #{value}" %><br/>
  
  <%records.length do |i|%>
  <%if i.checked == "true"%> 

  <% if (records.key?(key)) %>
   <%postage_rate = records["#{key}"]%>  

  <%= f.hidden_field :service_name,:value=>key%> 
  <%= f.hidden_field :postage_rate, :value=>postage_rate%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :price_and_rate, :value=>((p.price * order_item.amount)
   + (postage_rate * order_item.amount)).round(2)%>
  <%= f.hidden_field :admin_charge, :value=>(((p.price * order_item.amount)+ 
  (postage_rate * order_item.amount))/100).round(2)%><br/>

  <%end%>
    <%end%>
      <%end%>
         <%end%>
```

The service_name gets assigned a value but postage_rate is not. I cannot figure out why. I get the following exception:

Mysql2::Error: Column 'admin_charge' cannot be null:
INSERT INTO `curriers` (`admin_charge`, `amount`, `buyer`, `cart_id`,
`order_item_id`, `postage_rate`, `price`,
`price_and_rate`, `seller`, `service_name`)
VALUES (**NULL**, 1, 'xxxxxx, xxxxxx@xxxxx.com, +xxxxxxx, xxxxx ,xxxx, United Kingdom ,xxxxxx', 5, 20, **NULL**, 45.34, **NULL**, 'xxxxx,xxxxx,xxxx, Woking, xxxxxx, United Kingdom', **'UPS Saver'**)

It throws an exception because the value is not assigned to postage_rate.

Answer (score 0):

**First Step**: I have turned the :service_name and the :postage rate into one string:

```
<%service_name = "#{rate.service_name} , 
 # {(@bank.get_rate(res.rate_estimates[0].currency,:USD) 
 * (rate.price).to_f/100).round(2)}"%>
```

**Second Step:**  I displayed radio buttons using:

```
<%res.rates.sort_by(&:price).each do |rate|%>
 <%service_name = "#{rate.service_name} , 
 #{(@bank.get_rate(res.rate_estimates[0].currency,:USD) 
 *(rate.price).to_f/100).round(2)}"%>


 <%postage_rate = (@bank.get_rate(res.rate_estimates[0].currency,:USD) 
 *(rate.price).to_f/100).round(2)%> 

 <%service_names << service_name%>
 <%=f.radio_button :service_name,service_name%> <%= service_name %> <br/>
 <%service_names.length do |i|%>
 <%if i.checked == "true"%> 

 <%= f.hidden_field :service_name,:value=>service_name %>  

        <%end%>
     <%end%>
 <%end%>
```

[image]

**Third Step:** I deleted the :postage_rate, :price_and_rate, and :admin_charge attributes from curriers table and add them to order_items table instead. The :service_name attribute I left in curriers table. I did this because after saving the :service_name attribute in curriers table as string ( like UPS Standard, 40.93 ) and using the 'match' method I could take out the number 40.93 from matchdata to string and then to float:

```
 def get_postage_rate
 "#{service_name}".match(/(\d+)\.(\d+)/).to_s 
 end
```

**Fourth Step:** I wanted my 'ADD' button to do two things: a) to save the :service_name attribute in curriers table and b) to update the :postage_rate, :price_and_rate, and :admin_charge attributes in order_items table at the same time. So, I changed my create method in CurriersController file:

```
 def create  
 @currier = Currier.new(params[:currier])

 if @currier.save

 @order_item = OrderItem.find(@currier.order_item.id)
 value = @currier.get_postage_rate

          @order_item.update_attributes(
              :postage_rate =>value.to_f, 
              :price_and_rate => ((@order_item.price * @order_item.amount)
          +(value.to_f *   @order_item.amount)).round(2),
              :admin_charge => (((@order_item.price * @order_item.amount)+ 
          (value.to_f * @order_item.amount))/100).round(2)
            ) if @currier.service_name != ""

     flash[:notice]= "Currier #{@currier.service_name} was successfully created."
     redirect_to :controller=>'checkout',:action => 'rate_response'

     else  

      @page_title = ''
      render :action=>'new'
         end
      end
```

[image]

[image]

[image]